# .htaccess redirecting the display images in other server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Can you help me out with my problem about .htaccess redirecting the display images in other server..

i got this in my .htaccess

```
      Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews    
      RewriteEngine On    
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$ http://www.newurl.com/folder/folder/i/m/img_4fa231e793149_s.png
```

[NC,L]

this htaccess only redirects only one images which is img_4fa231e793149_s.png

i would like to do is to retrieve all the images which is here ->http://www.newurl.com/folder/folder/i/m/...

any help is appreciated thanks a lot....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your captured group `$1`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews    
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /magento/media/catalog/product/i/m/   

RewriteRule ^(img_[^.]+\.(?:jpg|png|jpeg|gif))$ http://www.tokopals.com/Dan/Magento_images/i/m/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: @anuhava-Thanks for the answer

i tried your code but what happen is the picture is not displaying anymore... what us the code will be in the php file?..

Comment: That could be because image doesn't exist onnewurl. Can you provide some examples of the your original image name and image name on newurl path?

Comment: Original url-->http://danstore.saatsocial.com/magento/media/catalog/product/i/m/img_4fa231e83fba9_s.png -------------------

New url-->http://www.tokopals.com/Dan/Magento_images/i/m/img_4fa231e83fba9_s.png ------------------

i put my htaccess in here-->danstore.saatsocial.com/magento/media/catalog/product/i/m/.htaccess

Comment: Still not working.. How can i put a value in $1?

so that i will put the value on in... becayse my plan is put a while loop which is the name if the images like..

while(code){
$1 = $image_name 
}

thanks..

Comment: `$1` is already populated by grouping the pattern in brackets, which is `(img_[^.]+\.(?:jpg|png|jpeg|gif))`

Comment: Also make sure this .htaccess is even being read by putting same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: what you mean with the garbage text on the top of .htaccess? you mean i put some ramdom text?... sorry i'm really new with this htaccess..

Comment: adfadfadf

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews    
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /magento/media/catalog/product/i/m/   

RewriteRule ^(img_[^.]+\.(?:jpg|png|jpeg|gif))$ http://www.tokopals.com/Dan/Magento_images/i/m/$1 [NC,L,R]---------------
nothing happen...

Comment: If nothing happens the this htaccess isn't even used. When I come back to my computer I will suggest you another rule.

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess in magento directory?

Comment: Yes i have... actually right now the codes that are you giving i put it in my localhost not yet in the server.. and by the way how i can determine which is which the images is?

Comment: Can you check your filesystem and tell the paths wherever you have .htaccess under `/magento` folder

Comment: I didn't understand this question `how i can determine which is which the images is`

Comment: oh I'm sorry, C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\media\catalog\product\i\m\.htaccess <-- this is directory i put the htaccess. what ive done is the images are move in other server which is i've already done.. the problem now is to retrieve the images in magento using redirect in --->http://www.tokopals.com/Dan/Magento_images/i/m/img_4fa231e83fba9_s.png... i hope you understand...

Comment: Is there any other rule in this `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\media\catalog\product\i\m\.htaccess` or this is the only rule?